# How to auto scroll down iframe to bottom without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to scroll down an iframe (local file .html) but isn't working.
I've tried this code, but the iframe stays in the same position (the scroll bar):

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
var myIframe = document.getElementById('01');
myIframe.onload = function () {
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(200, 300);
}

</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>

<iframe id="01" src="Content.html" name="iframe2" width="150" heigth="200"></iframe>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: putting the script after the iframe in the html should help other wise the script runs too early ( also its kinda weird having SCRIPT in all caps as the finish tag)

Comment: I tried, but isn't working

Comment: ok the scrollTo function is not visible from outside an iframe due to security reasons Id guess what you can do however is (if you have access to the Content.html ) add a script to that that scrolls to the position and if you need to pass the position from outside pas it via query/hash parameters in the url

Comment: Let me see if I get it... (I have access to content.html, its a test file) in content.html I'll put the script to scroll down?

Comment: yes just something like <script> window.onload=()=>{scrollTo(200,400);}</script>

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much. But one more question, is possible to auto scroll down the iframe inside him?

Comment: wait another iframe ?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled... put the auto scroll on content.html, like the script to scroll down

Comment: in my example its alredy written like a script tag that can be inserted into html oO

Comment: Yes, I know, but this command only works one time (on load), can I make this a repetitive function? (Every update scroll down or every x seconds).

Comment: <script> function scrollToPosition(){{scrollTo(200,400);} window.onload=()=>scrollToPosition}</script>  now you can call scrollToPosition from wherever you want

Comment: Thank you, worked, and I can manipulate now.